# QwtPlotMarker & Autoscale #Qt

Tags: qt, markers, curve, qwt

I have a "problem" with Qwt.
When I set a QwtPlotMarker, the autoscale functions of the X & Y axis are bound to my QwtPlotCurve only. 
Is there a way to take in consideration my markers without plotting another curve for my lines ?

I want to set 2 horizontal lines (HLine) in order to show the limits where the curve should be in.

Thanks.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
marker->setItemAttribute( QwtPlotItem::AutoScale, true );
```